# How should I set the PATH variable on my Mac so the Hombrew-installed tools are found?

Tags: macos, git, homebrew

Trying to set up [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) on a new Mac (on previous Macs I would install packages from source).

The first package I tried to install was Git:

```
$ brew install git
```

Installation went OK, but `which git` still shows the one in `/usr/bin/git` that came along with **Lion** (I think?). And not the one in `/usr/local/bin/git` that was just installed.

```
$ echo $PATH
/Users/meltemi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/bin:/Users/meltemi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/bin:/Users/meltemi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin:/Users/michael/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/opt/subversion/bin:/Developer/Additions/checker/:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin
```

As you can see `/usr/bin` defaults to before `/usr/local/bin` in the `$PATH`

So, I'm confused! I thought the point of **HomeBrew** (and something the creators seem to brag about) was that you don't have to mess with the `$PATH` variable!?!

So, what did I do wrong?

Comment: did you mess with your path previously and maybe put them in the wrong order? Also Im not sure why this is a "bragging point" form homebrew... it not like the concept of a path or modifying it is a complex thing which involves authoring and sprinkling 10 different plists across your system with special permissions or something....

Comment: path, well the part that isn't RVM related, should be standard issue. And no, I'm not complaining about having to change the path. It's just that they seem to repeat the claim `If you choose /usr/local, everything 'just works!'` that I have to wonder what I'm missing...because it doesn't "just work".

Answer (score 90, accepted):

I found this related post to be very helpful. Instead of changing the `$PATH` variable, it just has you simply edit your `/etc/paths` file.

[Homebrew wants me to amend my PATH; no clue how](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10343834/homebrew-wants-me-to-amend-my-path-no-clue-how)

As soon as I followed the directions and put `/usr/local/bin` above `/usr/bin`, my issues were resolved.

1. On OS X, open Terminal
2. Type the command: `sudo vi /etc/paths`
3. Enter your password if you're asked for it
4. You will see a list of paths. Edit them so that `/usr/local/bin` path is entered above the `/usr/bin` path
5. *Save and quit
6. Restart Terminal

Here's what mine looks like after I did that:

```
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
```

*To save and quit type a colon (`:`), then type `wq` (to write and quit at the same time), followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

You can also open the `/etc/paths` file in a graphical text editor and edit it that way.

Credit to [fengd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/385257/fengd)
over at Stack Overflow for his answer over there.

Comment: For vi dimwits (like me) use d to cut a line and p to paste it when in command mode

Comment: I would use caution with this -- the better answer is to just amend the path in .profile / .bash_profile and export it there.  By changing /etc/paths, you (potentially) affect all system processes; changing PATH in .profile / .bash_profile localizes the preference to both your account and those commands invoked via the command shell (which, in my case for development, is what I want).

If you're really cautious, you can do what @Aristotle Pagaltzis suggests in the answer below.

Comment: Is there some point when you stop to consider there is something terribly wrong that a simple install from a package manager designed for OSX is failing out-of-the-box? Changing up your path is a potentially breaking "fix" and BTW, the reason I stumbled on this proposed fix is that brew fails to update my path, also, but "paths" is already in the correct order.  Another dead-end.  Stop the madness, fix the root cause.

Comment: Also, there’s `path_helper` and `/etc/paths.d`.

Answer (score 32):

This answer is obsolete. The preferred Homebrew `PATH` ordering used to be as explained, but that is no longer true. However, the approach is more generally applicable, so for interest’s sake, I’m leaving it up.

---

You shouldn’t.

Homebrew intentionally keeps `/usr/local/bin` *after* `/usr/bin` in the path for maximum compatibility. Reversing the order of these directories in `PATH` by editing `/etc/paths` would mean that *all* programs anywhere on the system, no matter how they were started, will get the Homebrew version of a command. But some may specifically expect Apple’s version, or just not be able to use a newer version, etc.

How to preserve this principle and still get the Homebrew-installed version of `git`? As the saying goes, all problems can be solved with a layer of indirection (except having too many layers of indirection). — Or in this case, as it turns out, two layers.

Specifically, it’s been part of my Unix habits to have a `~/bin` directory which I put at the start of my `PATH`. This is one of the first bits in my `.bashrc`:

```
[[ :$PATH: == *:$HOME/bin:* ]] || PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH
```

This checks whether `PATH` contains `~/bin`, and if not, prepends it. With that in place, then selectively making just the Homebrew-managed `git` take precedence over the system version (instead of *every* Homebrew-managed binary), and just for your shell sessions (instead of *all* programs started from anywhere, including GUI programs), is as simple as symlinking it:

```
ln -s /usr/local/bin/git ~/bin/git
```

You *could* symlink `/usr/local/Cellar/git/1.8.2.1/bin/git` directly, but then you would have to fix your symlink every time you did a `brew upgrade git` (directly or indirectly). By symlinking to Homebrew’s fixed-location symlink, you don’t have to worry about it.

So you add a directory to your `$HOME` so you can add it your `PATH` so you can symlink to a symlink, and that fixes your problem and puts a smile on Dr Seuss. Yo dawg I herd you like symlinks so we put a path in your `PATH` so you can symlink while you symlink.

Comment: Excellent, this answers exactly what I was wondering!

Comment: This SEEMS like the right answer, but I can't figure out the exact commands to run.  I keep getting "File exists" when creating symlinks.

Comment: Not enough detail to help you, sorry.

Comment: @Ryan make sure you have the order of args right in the `ln` command.  The first path is the target, and the second is the symlink

Comment: -1 You wrote "Homebrew intentionally keeps `/usr/local/bin` after `/usr/bin` in the path". This is wrong. It's actually the opposite. If you mess this up `brew doctor` will tell you [`Error: /usr/bin occurs before /usr/local/bin`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11335908/brew-doctor-says-error-usr-bin-occurs-before-usr-local-bin-how-to-fix). In the case when there is any risk of the homebrew version causing instability due to overriding the system version, Homebrew mitigates by leaving the brewed version unlinked. eg. openssl, curl or using a different name eg. gsed for gnu-sed.

Comment: It used to be the case – hence the whole question in the first place. But you are correct that it is no longer true.

Comment: true that, on el cap, I failed with the obsolete answer and succeeded with (I use ZSH) editing the path's order in .zshrc `export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"`

Answer (score 19):

You haven't done anything wrong, but it does seem pretty clear that if you had `/usr/local/bin` in your path before `/usr/bin` this specific problem would go away.  The easiest fix is to do just that and put something like

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

in your `~/.bash_profile` so everything that Homebrew installs is found first.  That's the way that I have it set up on my Mac, and it has worked for me for this long, however, YMMV.

It does appear that they believe it would work with `/usr/local/bin` being *after* `/usr/bin`, so while I might have mucked up my own `$PATH`, I can see where their documentation lacks:

> Note that you should put `/usr/local/bin` after `/usr/bin`
>   because some programs will expect to get the system version of,
>   e.g., ruby, and break if they get the newer Homebrew version.

From [Discrepancy between wiki & brew doctor #10738](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/10738). 
Note that this document goes on to say,
"The FAQ (the above quote) refers to the PATH setting for GUI apps;
the doctor (the advice to put `/usr/local/bin` ahead of `/usr/bin`
in your PATH) refers to the PATH setting for CLI apps."

Comment: Won't this leave two `/usr/local/bin`s in my `$PATH`? I believe so. I wonder if we should instead be editing the order of the default paths in `/etc/paths` or the contents of `/etc/paths.d`? But this will affect every user...maybe not a bad thing. Anyway, just wanted to see how other people have approached this.

Comment: @Meltemi, the spirit of this answer is correct: update your `PATH` (in the manner of your choosing) to have `/usr/local/bin` precede `/usr/bin`. I personally update my `PATH` in `.bash_profile` as suggested here.

Comment: @Nick- interesting information...and only serves to confuse matters (at least *my* matters)...Homebrew docs seem to imply that Terminal commands should pick up apps in `/usr/local/bin` even though it trails `/usr/bin` in the path. But GUI apps need special coddling? IT would seem *all* apps, GUI or not, need us to adjust the $PATH variable. So, what am I (or the Homebrew creators) missing?

Comment: I think Homebrew assumes you want to use the Apple supplied executable first - git is a change as until Lion it was not supplied by Apple thus Homebrew needed it - now you can use the Apple one,

Comment: I agree with Mark on this.  With MacPorts and Fink, the assumption was to provide a completely pristine, separate environment from anything Apple supplied out of the box.  Homebrew took the stance that Apple's stuff is great and not to avoid using it (why download another version of gcc when Apple's will likely do?).

Comment: In the interest of having the most up-to-date versions (Git as installed by Apple is 1.7.5.4, Homebrew's is 1.7.8.4) I've done as originally suggested and put /usr/local/bin first in my path. It may break stuff, but I guess I will find out. Thanks everyone for the advice here.

Answer (score 7):

I disagree with jthomas' answer.  Editing your /etc/paths file will change the load paths for all programs.  This could be dangerous if a system application is expecting to find a specific version of a binary but finds a different version because you have edited your paths file.  Instead, change your path variable in ~/.bashrc (or ~/.bash_profile). Then your load path will only change inside the terminal:

> # Add homebrew app to PATH
>   export PATH=/path/to/homebrew/app/bin:$PATH

Then reload bash or `source ~/.bashrc`, and you're good to go.  Since the homebrew path comes before anything else, bash will load the version that you downloaded with homebrew.

Comment: In OS X, the `.bashrc` isn't loaded by default. Do you manually source it?

Comment: Oh, yeah.  I came from OS X from Ubuntu and was used to having a `.bashrc` so I source it from my `.bash_profile`.  If you don't want to create the rc file, you can add the command to your `.bash_profile`.

Answer (score 4):

As I understand it, `brew` doesn't put anything in `/usr/local/bin` that collides (has the same name as) an Apple distributed executable.  Therefore, having `/usr/local/bin` in the path before `/bin` and `/usr/bin` shouldn't be an issue, because there should be no name collisions.  *However, see the issues with `ls` and `tar`, and using other package aggregators like `fink` and `port` (MacPorts), way below.

`Brew` does one of two things that I know of that help manage name collisions:

1. **`Brew` leaves unlinked kegs in the Cellar.**  To install stuff, brew leaves the tools where they are, and creates symbolic links to those tools in `/usr/local/bin`.  For tools which `brew` doesn't want a name collision with, it doesn't create a symbolic link.
2. **For many if not all of the standard tools which are also in `/bin` and `/usr/bin`, `brew` prefixes the link in `/usr/local/bin` with a "g", so for instance, to perform an `ls` with a brew version, use `gls`.**  Simply do an `ls -l` in `/usr/local/bin` and look for the linked files - those are the ones `brew` put there.  Note:  The `brew` installed tools that must be accessed by their real names are found in `/usr/local/Cellar/coreutils/8.21/libexec/gnubin`.

I don't put `/usr/local/bin` in my path for two reasons - those reasons are at the bottom of my answer.

To assess the name collisions in your system, use `brew doctor` and look for this section - 
Here's the `brew doctor`'s output of interest:

```
Warning: /usr/bin occurs before /usr/local/bin
This means that system-provided programs will be used instead of those
provided by Homebrew. The following tools exist at both paths:

    ctags
    emacs
    emacsclient
    etags
    ex
    git
    git-cvsserver
    git-receive-pack
    git-shell
    git-upload-archive
    git-upload-pack
    rview
    rvim
    view
    vim
    vimdiff
    vimtutor
    xxd

Consider setting your PATH so that /usr/local/bin
occurs before /usr/bin. Here is a one-liner:
    echo export PATH='/usr/local/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

**The reason I don't put `brew`'s tools first, in fact, not at all, is because the `brew` installed `ls` and `tar` commands do not handle the filesystem ACL properly, in fact, last time I checked (which was last week), *they weren't handled at all***.  This is a BIG problem, and to avoid it altogether, along with the associated `man` page configuration issue that tags along with setting the `$PATH` right, I make sure I put the `OSX` related tools, especially those found in `/bin` and `/usr/bin`, first.

**Another reason I don't even put `/usr/local/bin` in my path at all is because `brew` doesn't play well with others, and `fink` and `port` (MacPorts) have way more supported packages at present that I need *NOW***.  For instance, I can get `gnome-terminal` with `fink`, but it would be a big effort to construct a formula and do the same with `brew`.  So, I keep `/sw` and `/opt` in my search `$PATH` (for `fink` and `port`, respectively) and reference things I need from `/usr/local/bin`, including `gnat`, either spelled out, or I use `bash` `alias`'s, or I source a `setup` file for an entirely different environment when I writing `Ada` code.

The thing is, it really depends on what you want and need at the time.

Here's an example of the ACL problem that I mentioned above.

**With the standard `OSX` tools:**

```
$ /bin/ls -le /var/root | head -7
total 24
drwx------+  3 root  wheel  102 May 28  2013 Desktop
 0: group:everyone deny delete
 1: user:_spotlight inherited allow list,search,readattr,readextattr,readsecurity,file_inherit,directory_inherit
drwx------+  6 root  wheel  204 Sep 19 14:22 Documents
 0: group:everyone deny delete
 1: user:_spotlight inherited allow list,search,readattr,readextattr,readsecurity,file_inherit,directory_inherit
```

**and with the `brew` installed tools:**

```
$ /usr/local/bin/gls -le /var/root
/usr/local/bin/gls: invalid option -- 'e'
Try '/usr/local/bin/gls --help' for more information.
```

**and**

```
$ /usr/local/bin/gls --help | grep -i acl
```

You'll get similar results with `tar` and I don't know home many other `brew` tools, but who can afford to have something break 6 months down the road because of an `ACL` problem!

Comment: Thanks for the useful info.  As a note, however, on my system right now, I do have executables with the same name in both /usr/bin and /usr/local/bin (e.g., git, which IS symlinked, as you note).  So, they do conflict by default.  I also do want to override the system tools for my shell work.

Answer (score 4):

There's a whole slew of good answers here. Here's mine:

```
echo >> ~/.bashrc alias my="PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
. ~/.bashrc
my git --version # Brew's fancy git
git --version # Apple's old crusty git
```

Saves you having to create a separate alias for each program, and as a bonus it leaves the default installations accessible in case you need them.

Works just the same if you're using ZSH; just switch out `bashrc` for `zshrc`. You can switch out `my` for `_` or even `@` to save on typing.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than messing with the PATH at all (which in my history comes back to burn me months later) I added an alias for git in my zsh custom aliases directory (~/.zshrc/custom/git_alias.zsh).

`alias git='/usr/local/bin/git'`

Answer (score 1):

I prefer limiting changes to environvent variables like `$PATH` to users who actually want the change. Thus, I simply add the following to `~/.bashrc`:

```
export PATH="$(brew --prefix)/bin:$PATH"
```

Answer (score 1):

for Apple Silicon

```bsh
/opt/homebrew/bin
```

open your bash profile

```
vi ~/.bash_profile
```

add the following to your profile

```
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can issue the following command in a terminal, it will add the brew home directory + the /bin in the PATH of your whatever SHELL "rc" init file (bash, zsh, csh)

`echo "export PATH="'$PATH:$(brew --prefix)/bin' >> ~/.$(basename $SHELL)rc`

Enjoy !

Answer (score 0):

### Investigation:

I received the error "*command not found*" when executing a Homebrew command. However, I checked that I had `/usr/local/bin` in my path as per the other answers in this thread and indeed it was there. ?!?!?!?

An `ls -al /usr/local/bin` verified all my Homebrew stuff was living in this path.   Then it occurred to me: was the command failing `mtr` living here too?

```
ls -al /usr/local/bin|grep mtr
```

Returned no results.  Indeed the package `mtr` puking the error **DIDN'T** live in the default path. That certainly explains the "*command not found*" error.

### Solution:

Although everybody and the Homebrew documentation tell you to add `/usr/local/bin` to your path, there's one other thingy you need to add to your path:

```
/usr/local/sbin
```

`mtr` and certain other Homebrew packages require execution via `sudo` and will live in **s**bin as opposed to bin.

Adding this path to:

```
/etc/paths
```

will persistently add it to your paths and now when you execute one of these commands, it will work as intended-