# update git after upgrade to Mavericks

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, git, osx-mavericks

I've recently upgraded from Mac 10.6.8 (Snow Leopard) to 10.9.4 (Mavericks).

I had git 1.8.5.2 installed on the old system and want to update it now to the latest version. So I uninstalled git with the uninstall file, I tried to update it with Xcode but nothing works. Typing
$ git --version
I still get the response "git version 1.8.5.2 (Apple Git-48)"

If I try to download git from the git-scm.com page it will automatically download git 2.1.0 for Snow Leopard and if I try to download git installer I get the version for snow leopard.

Anybody got an idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I've had a lot of luck using the homebrew package manager on OS X. Check if you have it using your terminal:

$ which brew

If no path is given, install it:

$ ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"

Afterwards, diagnose and troubleshoot any problems, then make sure brew is up to date.

$ brew doctor
$ brew update

Before we install git make a note of a git that may still be being used:

$ which git

Go ahead and install git:

$ brew install git

Afterwards, open a new terminal (or tab or restart terminal) and see if we have a successful location - or a new location that matches with our fresh git install:

$ which git

If it seems to be pointing to an old location or something that does not involve /usr/local/bin (where homebrew references things) then you may need to adjust your shell path. Take a quick look at it with:

$ echo $PATH

You can review various ways to change it elsewhere. I recommend the following option, but there are other listed in the same article that may be simpler for you.

[How should I set the PATH variable on my Mac so the Hombrew-installed tools are found?](https://superuser.com/questions/324616/how-should-i-set-the-path-variable-on-my-mac-so-the-hombrew-installed-tools-are/580611#580611)

Comment: If you use software IDEs, some of them provide plugins or have source control implementations/libraries built for things like Git, SVN, Mercurial etc. that do not require updating or reinstalling your native or default SCM software (like your OS X git).

Netbeans, for example, has a plugin that uses JGit which is a a pure Java library implementing the Git version control system. Using something like the Netbeans IDE might be a potential work around for you.